Change nested child component styling in MaterialUI v5
How to apply custom styles to all textField components which are children of Dialog/DialogContent component?
I tried adding these styles to createTheme, but it doesnt work.
If thats not possible how to do it using a class e.g. form-field class?
      <Dialog ...>
        <DialogTitle>
          Edit Order
        </DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>
          <Formik ...>
            <Form>
              <TextField />
              <TextField />
              ...
            <Form/>
          </Formik>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>

import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiDialogContent: {
      styleOverrides: {
        textField: {
          padding-top: 0.5rem;
          padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
        }
      }
    }
    ...

.form-field {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}


const customTextField = {
paddingBottom: '0.5rem',
paddingTop: '0.5rem',
}
      <Dialog ...>
    <DialogTitle>
      Edit Order
    </DialogTitle>

    <DialogContent>
      <Formik ...>
        <Form>
          <NameField sx={customTextField} />
          <IdField sx={customTextField}/>
          ...
        <Form/>
      </Formik>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>

you need to overrides style with sx={{style here}} in MUI component link here: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#the-sx-prop
